# Django - Converting from {{STATIC_URL}} to {% static %}

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have the following line of code in my base file:

```
document.write('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/' + 
    images[selected_image] + '" alt="' + images_text[selected_image] + '"  
        title="' + images_text[selected_image] + '" class="image_random" />');
```

Recently I have upgraded from Django 1.6 to 1.11 and am switching from using STATIC_URL to using {% static %}. However, with this line of code in particular, I am having trouble with quotation parsing, given how the image is randomly selected and thus me using the document.write method in my base.html file. Could someone show me the proper way to do this conversion, since all of my attempts have failed (they always involve extraneous string literals, even when I am sure that I am balancing my quotes correctly.

Comment: Do you have this line of code in the html file?

Comment: Yes, it is in the HTML file.

Comment: In other instances I don't use document.write, since I know exactly which image I will be using beforehand.

Comment: You can't use `{% static %}` in javascript. It needs to be evaluated when the template is rendered. Javascript cannot access it

Comment: So what is a workaround? Previously, {{STATIC_URL}} had worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to use `{{STATIC_URL}}`(or any kind of variable) inside js file, you'll have to inject it from the the template directly to the html, and only than use it on your script, for instance:

`index.html` (rendered by django view):

```
<script>
  var staticUrl = '{{STATIC_URL}}';
</script>
<script src="your-script.js"></script>
```

In `your-script.js`:

```
console.log(staticUrl);
```